# Resultado de uma função em um array

Tags: php

Gostaria de inserir o ano atual em uma propriedade do tipo array de uma classe.

Tentei utilizar a função `date('Y')` diretamente na atribuição da propriedade, porém como  não deu certo.

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    public $myArray = [
        'teste' => 'valor',
        'ano' => date('Y')
    ];

    // código
}

var_dump( (new MyClass())->myArray );
```

Temporariamente, resolvi esse problema inicializando esse valor no método construtor da classe:

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    public $myArray = [
        'teste' => 'valor',
        'ano' => ''
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myArray['ano'] = date('Y');
    }

    // código
}

var_dump( (new MyClass())->myArray );
```

Existe alguma forma de atribuir o resultado de uma função numa propriedade, sem recorrer a uma atribuição através do construtor?

Não gostaria de utilizar o construtor pois planejo deixar essa variável como [`static`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Até onde sei, não é possível definir uma propriedade com valor de função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia usar um `GETTER`... é feio e sujo, mas pegue como modelo didático.
Se puder dar mais alguma informação sobre o comportamento da classe fica mais fácil dar um exemplo real.

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $myArray = array( 'teste' => 'valor' , 'ano' => null );

    public function __get( $name )
    {
        return static::$myArray;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        static::$myArray['ano'] = date('Y');
    }
}

var_dump( (new MyClass())-> myArray );
```

Output:

```
array(2) { ["teste"]=> string(5) "valor" ["ano"]=> string(4) "2014" }
```

Comment: Acabei implemento um getter estático nesse caso, inserindo a posição com valor dinâmico na variável estática.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente não da pra por métodos ou funções em propriedades no PHP, segundo a própria documentação [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Como alternativa pensei em declarar esses tipos com constantes utilizando o [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");

define("DATA",date("Y"));

class MyClass {
  // talvez
  //const DATA = DATA;

    public $myArray = DATA;

    // código
}

var_dump( (new MyClass())->myArray );

?>
```